# Excel time difference, including hundredth of a second

Tags: excel, time

i want to calculate time difference using excel, between two cells containing numbers in format hh:mm:ss,00. a simple subtraction doesn't work. Anyone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two cells contain valid time values then a subtraction **should** work assuming you are subtracting the smaller value from the larger one (Excel doesn't like negative time values unless you use 1904 Date System).

What formula did you try? What result did you get, what result do you expect?

Comment: For example: A1 = 12:01:00.35, A2 = 12:05:33.45, expected 00:04:33.10, but im getting an error (#value) when i do "=A2-A1". All cells have the same format(hh:mm:ss,00).

Comment: If I type those times into A1 and A2 and use that formula I get that result as I expected. If the times were simply text formatted I would expect the formula to work also.....where is the data from? Are there any additional characters (like space type characters at the end). If you use this formula to get the length of data what result do you get =LEN(A1) ?

Comment: I´ve done it again and its working, but when i double click the cell after write the time i want the hundredth part of the time resets to 00, do you know what can be causing this, i'm searching but didn't find a solution.
Edit: It's from the number format hh:mm:ss,00. It replaces what i wrote by the two 00 on the format

Comment: It's working now. I made it by formatting the time cells as text, and then made "=A2-A1" on a cell with the format (hh:mm:ss,00). A bit strange because it's text, but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty much dead now but I was looking at this earlier while trying to make a good formula to calculate hours worked in an office. Like by hour and minute. What I came up with was this:

```
=HOUR([@[Time Ended]])-HOUR([@[Time Started]])+(MINUTE([@[Time Ended]])-MINUTE([@[Time Started]]))/60
```

This was the formula I used in my hours column in my table to calculate the hours worked from two times, Time Started and Time ended. Notice I had to do the hour and minutes seperately, this is because there are two different functions for these. There is also a function for the seconds in a time, if you include seconds in the inputed time. Adding this into the formula above wouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the If function so that you don't get the negative error. Do

Instead of =TEXT(A1-B1)

You can do:

```
=IF(A1 > B1, A1 - B1, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, found this out.

```
=VALUE(LEFT(B4,8)-LEFT(A4,8))+VALUE((RIGHT(B4,3)/86400000)-(RIGHT(A4,3)/86400000))
```