# How to find Time difference in millisecond in excel

Tags: excel

Time 1 :2014-10-17 06:08:53,793

Time 2 :2014-10-17 06:08:56,188

`flow start time` `flow end time`

*2014-10-17 06:08:56,632* **2014-10-17 06:08:56,674**

*2014-10-17 06:09:57,479*   **2014-10-17 06:09:57,517**

*2014-10-17 06:10:00,763*   **2014-10-17 06:10:00,809**

I need to find the difference in hours,minutes.second and millisecond. Please give me a excel formula for that.

Answer (score 3):

If your values are valid date/time values you can just subtract one from the other e.g. with earlier time in A2

`=B2-A2`

custom format result cell to the requisite format, e.g.

`[h]:mm:ss,000`

Comment: I have done the same as what you said, but i'm getting result as #VALUE! not a difference in time

Comment: Excel wouldn't let me format it with a comma in the custom format field (Office 2010), I had to modify my timestamps to change commas `,` to full stops `.`. As someone said in another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10777509/3887715), make sure to subtract the larger (later) time from the smaller (earlier) time.

Comment: If "hh:mm:ss,000" or "hh:mm:ss.000" works seems depending on regional settings.